# memory issue in gatsby mdx file

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

working on the Gatsby project where using MDX files to show a content on website.

the problem is that I have created one react component and I'm using this component in MDX files and passing HTML string data through that component but the problem is when I analyze my project using webpack-bundle-analyzer I noticed that whichever MDX file usage CustomeTable component is becoming very heavy (8-10Mb file size due to that custom component). so is there any way to optimize this or reduce size of that file who usage that custom component

the data I'm passing through the component is big table, below is just a small example.

//Mdx file

```
---
title: "iOS Screen Share"
date: 
description: "Screen Share feature"
type: "docs"
order: 3
folder: "Features"
category: "references"
section: "example features"
slug: /example/features/ios/
---

import { CustomTable } from 'smooth-doc/components'

<CustomTable
  data={[
    {
      content: `
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>    
                            <td><b>Class</b></td>
                            <td>Sample Handler</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>    
                            <td><b>Delegate Method</b></td>
                            <td>(void)processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withType:(RPSampleBufferType)sampleBufferType; get buffer frame</td>
                        </tr>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            `,
        },
    ]}
/>
```

//CustomTable.js

import React from 'react'

```
export function CustomTable({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          className="overflow-desktop mb-5"
          style={{ overflowY: 'auto' }}
          key={index}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

look in the screenshot the size of iosscreenshare.mdx is getting 7Mb because I have used above CustomeTable component in that file

[image]